# insertion in the description of external affiliate product url in the single_product.php page of woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shorten_product_long_descrition', 20 );
function shorten_product_long_descrition( $content ){
 global $product;
// Get product id
 $product_id = $product->get_id();

 // Get url
 $url = $product->add_to_cart_url();
 // Only for single product pages
 if( ! is_product() ) return $content;

 // Set the limit of words
 $limit = 13;

 if (str_word_count($content, 0) > $limit) {
     $arr = str_word_count($content, 2);
     $pos = array_keys($arr);
     $text = '<p>' . substr($content, 0, $pos[$limit]) . "..<a href='" . $url . "' class='goto_more_offer_tab button'>...continua la lettura</a></p>";
     $content = force_balance_tags($text); // needded
 }
 return $content;
}
```

The code works, in the single product page it displays the url ($url), but when I open the home page of the website I no longer see the content.
What am I doing wrong?
thank you

Comment: What is a "php code wordpress woocommerce url external single product"? Don't abuse the title for keyword tagging, that's what SO has tags for. As a new user, also read [ask] and take the [tour]. For example, interpretations like "code works" are nothing to work with. You'll need much more detail than that, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: insertion in the description of external affiliate product url in the single_product.php page of woocommerce